# Maple code that *should* calculate primitive roots modulo n

Tags: maple

The code is:

```
primroot:=proc(n)  
  local tot,i,j, facts,l,k;  
  tot:=phi(n);  
  facts:=factorset(tot);  
  for i from 2 to n-1 do  
    for j from 1 to nops(facts)-1 do   
      for k  from 1 to nops(facts) -j  do  
        if  (i^(tot/(facts[j]))mod(n)!= 1) and ((i)^((tot)/(facts[j+k]))mod(n) !=1 )   
              then print(i);
               fi;  
       end do;   
      end do;  
     end do; 
    end proc:
```

This program works great for phi(n) values that have two factors, but anything else and it gives garbage answers.

Can anyone tell where I went wrong?
Thanks! And it looks a lot prettier in maple, sorry it looks like this!

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'll do that right now. You do have a point - if someone else is wondering the same thing, how will they ever find this?

Comment: Much better now.  Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Among all the factors of the totient, your **if** statement only checks two before deciding to print **i**. So, of course, it works when there are only two factors, and it is likely to fail otherwise. Also, Maple's "does not equal" operator is **<>**, not **!=**.

Here's my primitive root procedure using the same variable names and general coding style as you did:

```
#Returns set of all primitive roots mod n.
primroot:= proc(n::posint)
uses NT= numtheory;
local tot:= NT:-phi(n), facts:= NT:-factorset(tot), i, j, ok, r:= table();
     if n=2 then return {1} fi;
     for i from 2 to n-1 do
          if igcd(i,n) <> 1 then next fi;
          ok:= true;
          for j in facts while ok do
               ok:= evalb(i&^(tot/j) mod n <> 1) 
          end do;
          if ok then r[i]:= i; fi
     end do;
     {indices(r, 'nolist')}
end proc:
```

It is easier to write and to understand in functional-programming style:

```
primroot:= proc(n::posint)
uses NT= numtheory;
local tot:= NT:-phi(n), facts:= NT:-factorset(tot);
     select(i-> igcd(i,n)=1 and andmap(j-> i&^(tot/j) mod n <> 1, facts), {$1..n-1})
end proc:
```

Comment: Hey! I put a lot of work into my Answer. A comment would be nice. I don't even know if you've seen it.